# Multiple XkbOptions in xorg.conf

Tags: xorg, x11, xkb

how should I write multiple XkbOptions in xorg.conf? I've tried "option,option,option", "option, option, option", "option option option" and none of these worked - only the first option was executed.

Comment: It should be the first, commas with no spaces. Can you post the exact line you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 11):

In the options there is an example generated by X11:

```
Option        "XkbOptions"    "lv3:ralt_switch,compose:caps"
```

As we can see it is separated by commas and no spaces. Also the option is a command a colon and a key. Again, no spaces.

This comes from this file:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and was setup that way as I was installing Ubuntu.